# Complexity of recursive algorithm, that finds largest element in an array

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

How to calculate complexity of ths recursive algorithm?

```
int findMax(int a[ ], int l, int r) 
{
    if (r – l == 1)
        return a[ l ];

    int m = ( l + r ) / 2;
    int u = findMax(a, l, m);
    int v = findMax(a, m, r);

    if (u > v)
        return u;
    else
        return v;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is recursive nor what language you're using specified in the question. Can you add more details please?

Comment: How can you not see that it's recursive? Look at lines 4 and 5. Also, the language is C.

Comment: It's recursive because there is a call to `findMax` inside the `findMax` method. Language really doesn't matter that much. To describe the problem you can do it in a pseudocode if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Master Theorem:

```
T(n) = a * T(n/b) + f(n)
```

Where:

- `a` is number of sub-problems
- `f(n)` is cost of operation outside the recursion; `f(n) = O(n`<sup>`c`</sup>`)`
- `n/b` size of the sub-problem

The idea behind this function is that you repeat the operation on the first half of items (`T(n/2)`) and on the second half of items (`T(n/2)`). You get the results and compare them (`O(1)`) so you have:

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + O(1)
```

So `f(n) = O(1)` and in terms of `n` value we get `O(n`<sup>`0`</sup>`)` - we need that to calculate `c`. So a = 2 and b = 2 and c = 0. From the Master Theorem (as correctly pointed out in comments) we end up with case where `c < log`<sub>`b`</sub>`a` as `log`<sub>`2`</sub>`2 = 0`. In this case the complexity of whole recursive call is `O(n)`.